# Safe conversion String of nested Lists to List - eval() and literal_eval()

Tags: python, list, eval

I need to read a few strings from a `.cfg` file, this is the `.cfg` format:

```
rangeList1 = [50,60],[100,200],[300]
rangeError = [100],[t],[50,100]
```

I want to convert it to a List of Lists **safely** so i use:

```
list(ast.literal_eval(limitList))
```

Which results as `[[50, 60], [100, 200], [300]]` , with type `List`

I understand the `eval()` is unsafe since the input string can result in a security breach.

The `ast.literal_eval()` [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) say:

> Safely evaluate an expression node.....

**Question:**

1. Since it's a critical issue i want to be sure, Does the `literal_eval()` method is 100% safe to use?
2. If not can you suggest another way to convert a string of nested lists to a list?

Comment: What is your specific use case? Why don't you use some simpler format like JSON?

Comment: @Blender this is a necessity, if it was up to me i would use JSON, but since it's defined to me this is format i need to work with.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` evaluates only Python literals, so your expressions won't be handled; it will parse only `[50, 60], [100, 200], ...`, so you'll have to effectively parse the rest of the file yourself. `ast.literal_eval` is *supposed* to be safe, so unless there is some unreported bug that's actively being exploited, I would consider it safe.

Comment: how do you want to handle `.. [t], ..`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may rewrite it in such style:

file:

```
{
    "rangeList1": [[50,60],[100,200],[300]],
    "rangeError": [[100],["t"],[50,100]]
}
```

script:

```
import json
with open("file", "r") as f:
    settings = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you would be better off talking a look at parsing with [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html?highlight=config#ConfigParser).

Comment: Can you be more specific? I know of 4 methods to get a value `get()`, `getint()`, `getfloat()` and `getboolean()`. at the current state this  answer should have been a comment...